# JSch: UnknownHostKey exception even when the hostkey fingerprint is present in the known_hosts file

Tags: java, ssh, vagrant, jsch

There are two questions about this exception already:

- [JSchException: UnknownHostKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063115/jschexception-unknownhostkey?lq=1) and
- [com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: UnknownHostKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003419/com-jcraft-jsch-jschexception-unknownhostkey)

I am using a Windows machine and trying to connect to a VM created with Vagrant running Ubuntu. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String host = "localhost";
    String username = "vagrant";
    int port = 2200;
    String privateKey = "C:\\keys\\openSSH_pair1\\open_ssh_private";
    JSch js = new JSch();
    try {
        js.addIdentity(privateKey, "pass");
        js.setKnownHosts("C:\\Users\\user\\.ssh\\known_hosts");
        Session session = js.getSession(username, host, port);
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected");
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

@Pascal suggests setting `strictHostKeyChecking` to `no`, which works for me, but this is not the preferred solution.  His preferred solution is to SSH from the command line so that the host will be added to the `known_hosts` file.  I have Git installed and executed `ssh -i openSSH_pair1\open_ssh_private vagrant@localhost -p 2200`
and received this output before being prompted for the pass phrase and establishing a connection

> The authenticity of host '[localhost]:2200 ([127.0.0.1]:2200)' can't
>   be established. ECDSA key fingerprint is
>   11:5d:55:29:8a:77:d8:08:b4:00:9b:a3:61:93:fe:e5. Are you sure you want
>   to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes Warning: Permanently added
>   '[localhost]:2200' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

So now my `known_hosts` file in `git_home\.ssh` contains an entry for `localhost:2200`, I also placed the `known_hosts` file into `user_home\.ssh`. I also put my private key on the VM I'm trying to ssh into and ran this to generate a public key and add it to the `authorized_keys`

```
ssh-keygen -y -f open_ssh_private > open_ssh_gen.pub
cat open_ssh_gen.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

However I still get this exception

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: UnknownHostKey: localhost. RSA key fingerprint is 50:db:75:ba:11:2f:43:c9:ab:14:40:6d:7f:a1:ee:e3
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkHost(Session.java:797)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:342)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at connect.Main.main(Main.java:24)
```

The answer to the other question suggests adding the below which doesn't work for me either

```
js.setKnownHosts("C:\\Users\\user\\.ssh\\known_hosts");
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you have added ECDSA host key to the `known_hosts`, as the `ssh` prefers that key type:

> ECDSA key fingerprint is 11:5d:55:29:8a:77:d8:08:b4:00:9b:a3:61:93:fe:e5.

But JSch prefers RSA key, which it won't find in the `known_hosts`:

> RSA key fingerprint is 50:db:75:ba:11:2f:43:c9:ab:14:40:6d:7f:a1:ee:e3

---

You probably need JCE to enable ECDSA In JSch.

See [JSch Algorithm negotiation fail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30846076/850848).

---

Or make `ssh` use RSA key with `-o HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-rsa`.
See [How can I force SSH to give an RSA key instead of ECDSA?](https://askubuntu.com/q/133172/280048)

You can also use `ssh-keyscan`:

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa example.com
```