# How to catch exception caused by external JARs

Tags: java, jsch

I have a scenario like this:

I am trying to execute a command (df -h i.e command to find disk free space ) on a database server. I  am trying to do so by using two JAR files i.e. jsch-0.1.51.jar and ganymed-ssh2-build210.jar .

Now when there is any worng credentails entered , It causes the below exception

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException
```

But when i try to catch that exception it says:

```
Unreachable catch block for JSchException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body
```

and the program fails how can i catch this "com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException" exception.???

Any suggestion is welcomed. Thanks in advance.

The full stacktrace is given below:

```
Connect fails with the following exception: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Select Option

session is down
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: session is down
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.openChannel(Session.java:752)
    at net.neoremind.sshxcute.core.SSHExec.exec(SSHExec.java:164)
    at org.nrift.SchMaint.controller.CheckSpaceServlet.doPost(CheckSpaceServlet.java:63)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: Try to catch only general "Exception".

Comment: Did you read this post? [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003419/com-jcraft-jsch-jschexception-unknownhostkey) Does your problem like that?

Comment: "com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException" might be a nested exception, which means it is preceded by "caused by" in your stack trace. To see if that is the case, call e.printStackTrace() in your catch block.

Comment: Is the method declared to throw a JSchException?

Comment: no,java isn't allowing me to throw an exception or catch it stating that the code is unreachable.

Comment: Which method are you trying? Have you cheked the java doc of that method?

Comment: I've requested to close this question as it doesn't specify how anything is called or how the catch is being implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Well, from what I can tell the method is not declared to throw an exception so your IDE is complaining that the exception is never thrown. As a workaround you can encapsulate the method call like this:

```
public void openChannelHelper() throws com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException {
    // call your method here.    
}
```

this should allow you to do something like:

```
try {
    openChannelHelper();
} catch (com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException e) {
    // handle the exception here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have written multiple catch block but order is incorrect. You should try bellow

```
try {
    //your code will be here where JSchException may occur 
} catch (com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException e) {
    // write here what you want if JSchException occur
} catch (Exception e) {
    // this block for other exception
}
```