# I'm trying to use Jsch to establish an SSH connection in Java.I got the Exception com.jcraft.jsch.jschexception unknownhostkey

Tags: jsch

```
jsch.setKnownHosts(new FileInputStream(SSHHostKey));
jsch.addIdentity(SSHKey);
session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
if (hostKey == null)
{
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
}
session.setPassword(pass);
session.connect();
channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();
sftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
```

still I get the same exception.
Can anybody tell me how to get/retrive HostKey? I am using Windows.

Comment: We do not know if your `hostKey` is null or not. If it is not null, your question is a duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/q/2003419/850848 If it is null, make sure you understand that you lose security by setting `StrictHostKeyChecking` to `no`.

Comment: I want to use StrictHostKeyChecking", "Yes". I have created HostKey manually looks like it gives me exception.

Comment: How did you *"created HostKey manually"*? What's your question actually? Are you looking for a correct format of the `hostKey`? Or for a way to pass it to JSch? What's wrong with the answers available at http://stackoverflow.com/q/2003419/850848

Comment: I have created HostKey manually looks like "SeverName ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAmyK7A4O/1XKsCyRpZDV7y+eW9yU9aZc2baSv" .                                                                                   I am checking Hostkey for null because If I want to make connection without key [with userName & Password ].                                            My problem is where I will get HostKey.

Comment: Do you mean where should you **put** the host key?

Comment: Correct format of Host Key or from where I can Get directly hostKey. Currently I am having Private & Public keys with me.

Comment: How to generate HostKey?