# PushCommand throws JSchException: UnknownHostKey

Tags: java, git, ssh, jgit

I'm using JGit to call a push command without using `StrictHostKeyChecking` set to `NO`, but I get the following error:

```
UnknownHostKey: <server hostname>. RSA key fingerprint is: <...>
```

The SSH key is set on the server, the known_hosts file contains the server hostname.
I can do a push from the command line, but not from code.

Here's my code:

```
SshSessionFactory sshSessionFactory = new JschConfigSessionFactory()
    {
        @Override
        protected void configure(final OpenSshConfig.Host hc, Session session) 
        {
            session.setPassword(passphrase);
        }

        @Override
        protected JSch createDefaultJSch(FS fs) throws JSchException
        {
            JSch jsch = super.createDefaultJSch(fs);
            jsch.removeAllIdentity();
            jsch.addIdentity("path to id_rsa");
            jsch.setKnownHosts("path to known_hosts");
            return jsch;
        }

    };

    //SshSessionFactory.setInstance(sshSessionFactory);

    TransportConfigCallback tcc = new TransportConfigCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void configure(Transport transport) 
        {
            SshTransport sshTransport = (SshTransport) transport;
            sshTransport.setSshSessionFactory(sshSessionFactory);
        }
    };

    pushCommand.setTransportConfigCallback(tcc);
    pushCommand.setPushTags().call();
```

Comment: Does your code succeed if you turn off strict host key checking (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003419/com-jcraft-jsch-jschexception-unknownhostkey)?

Comment: Yes, it works for stricktHostKeyChecking=no.

Comment: Then it is likely that your known_hosts cannot be found. You should debug step through `Session::checkHost()` (~line 704) to see what is going on.