# Unable to connect to SSH in Java

Tags: java, ssh, amazon-ec2, jsch

I'm trying to use JSch in Java to connect to one of my EC2 instances, but keep getting an "UnknownHostKey" exception message. Here's is (part of) my code:

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.io.*;

public class JSchTest {

    private String serverIp;

    public void testSshConnection() {

        try {

            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            jsch.addIdentity("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\.ssh\\id_rsa");

            Session session = jsch.getSession("ec2-user", serverIp, 22);
            session.connect(30000); // <-- this is where the exception is thrown

            ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("shell");

            // more code here...

            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();

        } catch (JSchException|IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setServerIp(String serverIp) {
        this.serverIp = serverIp;
    }
}
```

I've already added my public key to the `authorized_keys` file on the EC2 instance that I'm connecting to, and I know it works because I can connect to it using PuTTY. However as soon as I hit the line with the `session.connect()` in it, I get an exception like this:

> com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: UnknownHostKey: 10.114.2.115. RSA key fingerprint is 63:04:cf:60:4a:1d:47:35:12:0e:56:4f:5b:0a:c9:d4

What am I missing? How can I get this to connect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: UnknownHostKey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003419/com-jcraft-jsch-jschexception-unknownhostkey)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
```

As per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003419/com-jcraft-jsch-jschexception-unknownhostkey).

Comment: I just tried that, and while it does work, it has me a little concerned. Isn't this telling the JSch client to essentially circumvent part of the security?

Comment: @SoaperGEM  Yes, it is. Do not do that! @tom Never suggest anyone to use the `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` without explaining security consequences!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I would have suggested the first option in the link I cited ("Try to ssh from the command line and accept the public key") but I don't know how to do that in EC2.  Anyone?